# Logoff script to change user

Tags: scripting, windows-server-2003, logoff

Using Windows 2003, I'm look for a way to create a "logoff script" that will continue with the current logoff then immediately login another user.  So, "UserA" logs off.  Script fires to login "UserB".

This is part of an application upgrade for a computer where we have written the 'shell'; similar to a kiosk application.  For the upgrade we need to logon as 'Adminstrator' then, when the upgrade has completed, logoff 'Administrator' and logon as 'sample_user'.  We would like to accomplish this WITHOUT rebooting.

Note, I do not want a script that will initiate the logoff (i.e. "shutdown").  I'm looking for a [script](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781354.aspx) that will run upon the user logging off (set via Group Policies).  As above, the script should log a different user on.

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to take out the first part of your first sentence. That is just inviting drive by close votes.

Comment: And they will have no valid reason why this should be closed.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but running something after logoff feels like a major security breach. That script would have to run as "root" or "administrator" I guess. Is this to be used unattended?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't think it's possible in the stated way (script at logoff).

You'd have to set the machine to logon automatically as a specified account and then log off (having it log on automatically for you) and then you'd have to disable that feature again afterwards, by placing a temporary logon script... generally sounds messy.

The actual setting can be made using tools like Microsofts Shared Computer Toolkit or similar (not so sure how the "normal" registry auto-login behaves at manual logout but I've had an XP kiosk that would automatically log on instantly, even if you logged out manually - you had to override it using some key like shift+logoff to be able to manually specify the login again, so somehow it can be made).

The "easiest" way might be to replace msgina.dll with someone of your own making...

**But** why are you doing this? Just use *runas* and start whatever you need to do as that other user without logging off the console user - it's a multi-user system afterall? The desktop is just fluff ^^

(*This will anyhow require that the user credentials are available to your script, which kind of makes it redundant as you compromise the security of that account - defying the purpose of having that second account in the first place, for whatever purpose it exists?*)

Comment: Though I'd like to say, "this is easy on Apache" ^^

Comment: Since this functionality is only needed for an application upgrade, compromising security isn't really a concern.  The upgrade will be performed by integrators that already have full control of the system.  The scripts are just to add as much automation as possible.

Comment: Yeah but still, why does it need desktop access for two users sequentially for an upgrade? I'd like to avoid such an application if I still administered stuff - they should rethink the process? (yes I'm being annoying I know ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your concern.  The "sample_user" is logged in like a kiosk application.  We need to logoff "sample_user" and login as "administrator" to perform an application upgrade.  We want to be absolutely sure that when "administrator" logs off then "sample_user" is logged back in.

Comment: Why does the administrator upgrade need an interactive desktop? Just do the upgrade while the sample_user is logged in? Elevate the upgrade process/scripts/executable to the administrator user (using runas for instance, where even profile loading is possible).

Comment: This is a common way to do admin-required upgrades on Windows boxes since the dawn of time - don't log off the current user, just runas the upgrade (can even right-click an installer/exe and select "run as.." in the ui and get full window support).

Comment: So after researching the "runas" option I've uncovered some other requirements.  There is also a need for support personnel to login to the machine, look at event logs, etc.  In this case we would like a "logoff script" that will ensure the "sample_user" is logged back in.

Comment: If the sample user is just a kiosk software, it might be simplest to get a kiosk software/addon that does this (always logs in). It will most likely replace msgina to do this but it'll work.

Looking at event logs doesn't require desktop login thou, just have them use their own machine's log viewer.

Answer (score 4):

I would try [setting the registry to autologon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231) with the user you want, and then simply logging off the admin user.  That should log your kiosk-user right back on.

Comment: An extra step you will have to take if the kiosk user is not a member if Administrators is to change the registry permissions on the auto-logon key to allow the kiosk user to update it; the kiosk user can then remove the change rights itself during its first login.

Comment: Admin tip: When using autologon, you can override by holding the shift key and the normal login dialog will appear instead of automatically logging in.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to login another user once the current user logs off (not sure if windows would let you...)

But you can use shutdown to logoff:

> ```
> shutdown /?
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some ideas that probaly fall into the "cheap hack" category:

How about logging in at UserB in the first place, and then using `runas /user:userA <cmd>` to run the first part of the install process?

If that's unacceptable, I know there's a way to make Windows workstations (those that aren't part of a Domain) automatically log in into a certain user account after a restart. Perhaps if you looked into which Registry changes happen, and duplicated them, a reboot would automatically log in that user. (Of course, as a final stage, after userB logs in, you would have to revert those changes :-)

It also occurs to me to wonder if perhaps there's a way for a service to force an open "login screen" to log in as a certain user. Maybe using some method like the way the Remote Desktop does it remotely... If that's possible, then you could create a service that you install before logoff of userA, that would trigger the login of userB.

Answer (score 1):

You can script it with VNC (there are many free versions, take your pick).  Set up a VNC server process on the machine to listen on localhost.  When the user logs off, your logoff script will connect to the machine using VNC and send the keystrokes necessary to log on the next user.  VNC uses the RFB (remote framebuffer) protocol; there are libraries for most popular languages, so you should be able to get something working quickly.  Or there are related [tools](http://www.vncrobot.com/) that [might](http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/rfbplaymacro/) help.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to run something like this as a normal script in a given language, it would most likely not work as when you log out of your account, all processes should be killed along with your running script.

You might be able to create some sort of 'service' that would run on a service account (i.e. always active) that would automatically do this user switching for you.

My bets are on Windows Powershell, although I'm not entirely sure what functionality it has as far as actually creating a service.

A quick search brings up the following (The second link is to a forum but it mentions running Powershell as a service and sending that service a parameter which would be the path to your user switching script)

[How to Create a Windows Service using Powershel](http://halr9000.com/article/444)

[Powershell Script as a Windows Service](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/37213-powershell-script-windows-service.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Windows 2003 server or a system with a "Group Policies" setup to test my hunch but you could take a look at SU ("switch user") for Windows. Originally part of the Resource Toolkit this has been extended to a new [SUperior SU](http://www.stefan-kuhr.de/supsu/main.php3). Do post the results/script if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this from the perspective of building a remote control utility (like VNC, etc). The big thing here is that if you want access to the Logon screen (i.e. the CTRL + ALT + DEL / username/password) part, the only kicker is that a Windows Service is the only component that can access this, so you'd have to create one.

The only problem I see with this technique as a whole is that even if you spent a great deal of effort getting it to work (and it would be a pretty big effort), the chances of this working successfully with the whole thing originating from a logoff script (i.e. when stuff is shutting down) are low even due to the number of things that can go wrong when logging back on as Administrator.

Just remember that for anything you need to run as an Administrator, there are easier ways in Windows to make that happen (such as Run As, changing the user permissions on the items that need to update, etc).